# RadioButton circle and dot color on selected

Tags: android, xml, button, styles

I'm trying to change the ugly pink color that radioButton has when on pressed. I've been looking for it but seems like no one has the proper answer on how to do it. Do you recommend me styles or do it programmatically?

This is my xml layout of the radioButtons:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btSig"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
        android:id="@+id/primero"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="pulsado"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
        android:id="@+id/segundo"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="pulsado"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
        android:id="@+id/tercero"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="pulsado"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        />
</RadioGroup>
```

[image: I want to change that pink color when onpressed.]
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to change the default RadioButton color *app-wide* is to change it in your `res` folder.
In your project, go to `app`>`res`>`values`>`colors.xml`. This XML file contains the colors for your app in HEX values.
You will most likely see three XML values under `<resources>`. Remember, the **colorAccent** value changes the RadioButton select color.  [image]

Comment: yeah, it changes everything but i know how to manage the color of the rest of the elements i have. So Thank you!

Comment: Great, glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can change it with like that `android:buttonTint="#a14545"`

Code Example

```
<RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_mini_layout_selection_word_types_all"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="all"
        android:buttonTint="#a14545" />
```

Comment: yes, but I don't want them to be checked because is the user who has to choose the answer, not me! And by doing it this way, the circle is the same color always and I only want to change the color once is selected. Just like the picture I posted.